# PrimeFaces 3.5 Editor can't clear text

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2, Glassfish 3.1, PrimeFaces 3.5. I copied demo from homepage which using PF 4.0. I remove PF function to work my PF version.

Here my code:

```
   <h:form id="form">

        <p:editor id="editor" value="#{editorBean.value}" width="600"/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top:10px">
            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="dlg.show()"
                             icon="ui-icon-disk" />
            <p:commandButton id="clearButton" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="editor.clear()"
                             icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:dialog header="Content" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true">
            <h:outputText id="display" value="#{editorBean.value}" escape="false" />
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
```

Submit button works well, but I can't clear editor text with Clear button. Does PF 3.5 support clear method? Hope anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the widgetVar attribute. Because it picks up the widgetVar value for clearing the editor section, not the id in your case.

It should be.

```
<p:editor id="editor" value="#{editorBean.value}" widgetVar="editor" width="600" />
```

Comment: It works now. Thank you. What's master if I don't use widgetVar and what is it? How can I save data (include HTML) to DB, which method will use. Hope you help me.

Comment: What are you using to persist data to your table. Hibernate or Simple connectivity using java. In both the case you have your getter/setter  as value in your backing bean. The getter value can be used and an insert query in the table might work.
2. Regrading widgetVar it is implemented by Primefaces. The PrimeFaces.cw() JS method creates a special JavaScript object, called widget. If you right click -- and do view Source you can see this function.http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/9281OS_Chapter_11_Writing_Custom_Components.pdf . Hope this pdf will make you understand.

Comment: I'm using Hibernate. I'm newbie JSF and PrimeFaces so I don't know how to save data to DB. Hope your help.

Comment: How is the structure, DAO? facade?

Comment: public class CalendarBean implements Serializable {
 
  private String value;

 public String getValue() {
  return value;
 }

 public void setValue(String value) {
  this.value = value;
 } 
 
You can use this structure of the backing bean and use getValue and save this value into you POJO and persist in you database. I cant say more untill i see your DAO Code. If possible can you please share save() code of your DAO.